# automate mouse up event in vbscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, mouseup

I want to automate a process to get all the advisory# from

https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/errata#?&col=portal_errata&language=All&portal_product=Red+Hat+Enterprise+Linux&portal_product_version=7&portal_severity=Critical,+Important,+Moderate,+Low

I am able to get the advisories on first page using vbscript,but when I send .click() event to the next page anchor tag or any of the page numbers nothing happens.
When I inspected the element the anchor tag attached with page numbers gets triggered by a mouse up event
next ›

Can anybody help please

Here is the code:

```
     Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

     Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set obj1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    wscript.sleep 5000

    url="https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/errata#?    &col=portal_errata&language=All&portal_product=Red+Hat+Enterprise+Linux&portal_product_version=7"

    Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     ie.ToolBar = 0

     ie.StatusBar =0 

     ie.Width = 100

     ie.Height = 100

    ie.Left = 0

    ie.Top = 0

     ie.Navigate(url)

     ie.visible=true

     For Each objWindow In objShellApp.Windows

         Wscript.sleep 1000

         If (Instr(objWindow.LocationName,"Red Hat")) Then

     Set ie = objWindow

     exit for

     'Wscript.echo objWindow.LocationName

    End If

   Next

   do until ie.readyState = 4 : wscript.sleep 10 : loop

   Wscript.sleep 10000

    set oElm=ie.document.getElementById("searchResults")

   if oElm Is Nothing then

     MsgBox("element does not exist")

   else

   Set objFileToWrite = 

   CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\RHEL7.html",8,true)

   objFileToWrite.WriteLine(oElm.innerHTML)

   objFileToWrite.Close

   Set objFileToWrite = Nothing       

   end if

  set Elems = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

  '    set Elems=ie.Document.getElementById("next")

  i=0

  For Each elem  In Elems

   REM Wscript.echo i & "-----------"

  Dim str

  str=elem.GetAttribute("class")

 If ( str="pager" And str <> "" ) Then 

 ContentStr = elem.GetAttribute("title")

 if (Instr(ContentStr,"Go to page 2")) then

'elem.fireEvent "onmouseup"

elem.click

 msgbox elem.GetAttribute("title")

  end if

 End If 

Next
```